# Null model in select in Angular template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a databound `<select>` element in an angular app. To bind it I am using:

```
<select id="AllKeyValuePairsInput" size="4" style="width:500px; height: 175px;" ng-options='item.key as (item.key + ": " + item.value) for item in data.availableOptions' ng-model="selected">
    </select>
```

In my controller I have the following code, that according to the Angular documentation should remove that initial dirty model:

$scope.selected = $scope.data.availableOptions[0];

But I still see an empty entry appearing first in the select. I have it up and running in JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/alchiggs/d12tdapv/

I'd be most grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. One last point, it's the first bit of Angular I've ever written, so please don't hate me!!!! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `loadInitialData` should look, note the change in the default value:

```
$scope.loadInitialData = function() {
    var initialData = [{"key":"Maximum length","value":"200mm"},{"key":"Maximum width","value":"5000mm"}]

    angular.forEach(initialData, function(object, index) {
        $scope.keyValuePairs.push({ key: object.key, value: object.value});
    });
    $scope.selected = $scope.keyValuePairs[0].key; // THIS IS THE CHANGE I MADE
}
```

I've set the default value using the `key` property and not the element itself because your `ngOptions` define that the **value** of each option is `item.key`

Comment: That's great - thanks, and thanks for not laughing at my first ever angular app. One point - if you comment out the initialData variable, the forEach loop and the $scope.selected line (esentially viewing the app as if no data is being loaded), the select then has an empty <option> again.....Can this be resolved in a similar way?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to remove the empty option in this case. The only "hack" I can suggest is using css `select > option[value='?'] { display:none;}` - But it's quite an ugly solution. BTW- great work for a first-timer :)